# how to get html input value from the web in python

Tags: python, django

when i access `www.sampleweb.com/reg/` i has an input values like .

`<input id="input-id" class="input-class" name="myinput" type="text" value="hello world">`

how can i get the `hello world` value of `www.sampleweb.com/reg/`'s input using python?

i think in accessing the  `www.sampleweb.com/reg/` is like this :

```
url = 'http://www.sampleweb.com/reg/'
urlopen(url)
```

is this correct in accessing the url?

can anyone can help me about my case?

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library called [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should parse html after gwetting it via urllib (as you mentioned) using any python html parser.
For example, using BeautifulSoup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs%29

In your case something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
inputs=soup.find("input", {"id": "input-id"})
print inputs[0]['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that using a [DOM Parser](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) is the best option to parse out the HTML of any resource.

However if "hello world" is the only thing you want out the HTML, then the quick and dirty approach would be:

```
toFind = '<input id="input-id" class="input-class" name="myinput" type="text" value="'
htmlStr = urllib.urlopen('yoururl.com/your/path').read()
value = htmlStr[htmlStr.index(toFind)+len(toFind):]
value = htmlStr[:htmlStr.index('\"')]
print value
```